# Changing desktop background does not work as root

Tags: gnome, python, autostart, desktop-background

I am trying to write a python script that changes my background periodically.

This is the relevant code where I change the background:

```
command = "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:" + file_path

status, output = commands.getstatusoutput(command)
```

If I run it as root it does nothing, but still returns with 0.
If I run it as myself, the background changes.

I want to run it as root because I have put a symlink to my file in /etc/xdg/autostart.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to run it as root, but if assume that the gsettings configuration file is not the same for root user and your current user. try to run :

```
sudo gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri
```

before and after running your script as root, to see if the root-backgroud have been actually changed.

Also, you might want to take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292578/setting-gsettings-of-other-user-with-sudo/20414532#20414532).

Hope this helps